# DataGridView column names not accessable after adding new column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, nullreferenceexception, datagridviewcolumn

I'm trying to add a column to an existing data grid view and I'm getting an error after adding a column. Referencing the column by it's name throws a null reference exception and after some debugging I noticed, the names of the columns have disappeared after adding a column.

Before I add a new column you can see in the first image, that each column has a name. After I add a column, the second image shows the names of each column as being empty. No code was changed and the column being added to the data grid view was the only change.

`DGV_List.Columns("Vendor").Visible = CB_Vendor.Checked`

[image: Normal operation]
[image: Error after adding column]

I've found one or two ways to get around this, such as directly referencing the column like `Me.Vendor.Visible`. But I'm curious why adding a new column could cause existing working code to fail.

Edit adding code

The code is really long so I'm linking it on pastebin. Also note the column was added manually and not with code. Nothing besides the form designer code changed when the error started.

Code that has null reference error after adding column

https://pastebin.com/inZCT27A

Form designer before adding column

https://pastebin.com/2nv33pA3

Form design after adding column

https://pastebin.com/7ULHpNwE

Comment: Post the code you used instead of those images.

Comment: Your comment… _”But I'm curious why adding a new column could cause existing working code to fail.”_ … it won’t. Simply adding a column as you state is not going to cause the other column names to disappear. The two pictures are tantamount to showing us a “before/after” picture of a car crash and then asking us… “why did the car crash.” There must be something else (you are not showing) going on. If this happens “after” the column has been added, the I suggest showing that code, otherwise speculation is all you will get.

Comment: Should I include the section of code that threw the error or the code from the form designer? The form designer is the only code that changed from before the issue to after the issue. Also the column was manually added to the form, not with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that the problem lies in “WHEN” the `CheckBox`s `CheckedChanged` event is fired.

If the check box is set to `True` in the designer, then, its `CheckedChanged` event will get fired "once" in the `InitializeComponent` method.

If the check box is set to `False` in the designer, then its `CheckedChanged` event will NOT be fired in the `InitializeComponent` method.

Because the check box is set to true in the designer, then "sometime" in the `InitializeComponent` method the `CheckChanged` event is going to get fired and when it does... you can NOT guarantee that the grid has been fully initialized.

Checking “anything” relating to the grid “before” it has been fully initialized is risky. This would easily explain some of the inconsistencies I and I am sure you have seen.

The main point would be that, because you DO want to reference the grid in the `CheckChanged` event of the check boxes, AND you DO want to have the check box initially checked, then you need to make sure the grid is fully initialized "before" you set the check box to `True/False` (checked/unchecked).

One way to do this is from the “designer”, UNCHECK the check boxes that reference the grid. This will prevent the `CheckedChanged` event from firing in the `InitializeComponent` method when the grid may not be fully initialized.

Then in the forms `Load` event, where we can pretty much guarantee the grid is initialized fully, set the check boxes state to checked. Then the `CheckedChanged` event can fire without errors. …

```
Private Sub MCRI_Checker_Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  CB_Description.Checked = True
  CB_Drawing.Checked = True
  CB_FilePath.Checked = True
  CB_Quantity.Checked = True
  CB_ReqType.Checked = True
  CB_Vendor.Checked = True
  CB_WhereUsed.Checked = True
End Sub
```

I hope this helps and makes sense.